# Mobile app markup bar support while editing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, android-app

When creating a question/answer on the Android app, it gives you a little bar above the keyboard to bold/italicize, add a link easily, add a picture etc.

When *editing* however, this bar isn't shown. To ease editing on mobile, it would be exceedingly helpful to have this bar show up. I find myself resorting to the full site to add a embedded link if I can't at the moment remember the exact syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you click on the **edit** option, the markdown toolbar is not displaying. But if you are click anywhere inside the question/answer box, you can see the markdown toolbar.

I tried to edit your post in the android app and I can see the markdown toolbar.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Toolbar]

Comment: I swear this has never popped up for me. Let me try again.

Comment: What!? It must be inconsistent, or I'm just extremely unobservant. Well, thanks.