# Formatting questions and answers in the Stack Exchange Android application?

Tags: support, android-app

I don't seem to find any tools in the mobile app while writing answers and questions; I only see them in the browser view.

Are there no tools in the Android app, or do I just overlook them?

Comment: Are you talking about the browser app on a mobile device or an actual mobile app?  I have access to the tools when I write answers and questions using the iOS app.

Comment: @PolyGeo Actual mobile app (android).

Comment: Related [Mobile app markup bar support while editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293077/312043) or dupe ?

Comment: @Arulkumar dupe, yes. Nice find!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android app does contain some basic icons to help you with formatting posts:

> [image: basic toolbar in app]

This appears when you focus the Body field. While not 100% the same as the web view, it's enough for basic markdown, so if one wants the full advanced editor, they can simply use mobile browser.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Somehow i never noticed it

Comment: Maybe because it's below the textbox, not above as in web.